# Find a one-to-one conformal map from $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1, Re(z)>0, Im(z)>0 \} \setminus \{ a(1+i) : a \in (0,1/2] \}$ to the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a one-to-one conformal map from $\Omega=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1, Re(z)>0, Im(z)>0 \} \setminus \{ a(1+i) : a \in (0,1/2] \}$ to the upper half plane.

My thoughts so far :
By applying the following maps , you can map $\Omega$ to $\Gamma=\mathbb{C} \setminus \left( (-\infty,0) \cup (\frac{9}{4},\infty) \right)$ .

$w=z^4$ then $\zeta = \frac{4w+1}{1-w}$ then $\eta = (w+\frac{3}{2})^2$

I thought these maps are the best ones to get the desired map (Do you think so ?), and I think it must be very routine to map $\Gamma$ to the upper half plane, but I don't see how?

Any hints or ideas is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sourav's comment (there is a shorter way to do the task) I Apply the following maps in order:

1- $w=z^4$

2- $\eta=\frac{4w+1}{w+4}$ The key step ! it allows me to securely use the root function

3- $\gamma = \sqrt{\eta} = r^{1/2}e^{i \theta/2} \ \ \ \ $  where $\ \eta= re^{i \theta} \ \ $ and $\ \  0<\theta<2 \pi$

4- $\zeta = \frac{\gamma + 1}{1- \gamma}$

5- $\psi=\zeta^2$ Now we've landed on the upper half plane :)

Answer (score 1):

First use $z \rightarrow z^2$ and then $z\rightarrow e^{-i\pi/2}z$ to map $\Omega$ to the right half unit disc with a slit , $(0,1/2]$.
From then on the strategy is explained in the first comment of this problem. [Conformal map from disk with a slit to the upper half plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604877/conformal-map-from-disk-with-a-slit-to-the-upper-half-plane)

Comment: Thank you so much ! I used your link and found the solution in much fewer steps.